# Extract text from a specific outline or destination (not page number) with pdfminer (Python)

Tags: python, pdf, outline, pdfminer

I’m using pdfminer.six to extract text from a PDF file. I’ve tried others PDF extractors, but only pdfminer handles the text they way I need.

I want to extract the text from a specific outline (bookmark) that matches a search criteria.

The `PDFDocument` class has the method `get_outlines` for extracting outlines. It returns a generator of tuples that contains the outline's *level, title, destination*, and other information. The "destination" value is a list made of a `PDFObjRef` class instance and other information.

This is how data returned from `get_outlines` looks like:

> *(...)*
>
> (1, 'account information client 20', [PDFObjRef:3918, /'FitH', 36], None, None)
>
> (1, ‘account information client 21', [PDFObjRef:3931, /'FitH', 36], None, None)
>
> *(...)*

The pdfminer documentation page says, ‘Some PDF documents use page numbers as destinations, while others use page numbers and the physical location within the page’.
The number of the `PDFObjRef` in the example above *is not a page number*: the PDF I used for this example has only 933 pages.

As I said in the beginning, I need to extract the text only from one of the many outlines the PDF file has.
With the following snippet, I can create a generator and extract every page in a sequence:

```
from io import StringIO

from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser

output_string = StringIO()
with open('samples/simple1.pdf', 'rb') as in_file:
    parser = PDFParser(in_file)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

result = output_string.getvalue()
```

But I don’t how to point to a specific page destination (or a page range, comprised between two destinations) and extract the text from only this fragment.

Can someone please help?
How do I convert PDFObjRef:3918 and PDFObjRef:3931 to a page number, or how do I extract data an interval like this?

I´m using Python 3.8.5, and pdfminer.six.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. 
But I developed a glitchy workaround: I use pyPDF2 to find the outline and its pages, extract them to a new PDF object, save it as a temporary PDF file (using Python built-in "tempfile" library), and then pass it to pdfminer extract its text.

It is not beautiful nor optimal, but it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
file_name = "./data/familia-ley-19968.pdf"
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import PDFStream, PDFObjRef, resolve1, stream_value
from typing import Any, Container, Dict, Iterable, List, Optional, TextIO, Union, cast
from pdfminer.psparser import PSKeyword, PSLiteral, LIT
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

def resolve_dest(dest: object, doc) -> Any:
    if isinstance(dest, (str, bytes)):
        dest = resolve1(doc.get_dest(dest))
    elif isinstance(dest, PSLiteral):
        dest = resolve1(doc.get_dest(dest.name))
    if isinstance(dest, dict):
        dest = dest["D"]
    if isinstance(dest, PDFObjRef):
        dest = dest.resolve()
    return dest

def parse(filename, maxlevel):
    fp = open(filename, 'rb')
    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    pages = {
            page.pageid: pageno
            for (pageno, page) in enumerate(PDFPage.create_pages(doc), 1)
        }
    
    outlines = doc.get_outlines()
    for (level, title, dest, a, se) in outlines:
        if level <= maxlevel:
            pageno = -1
            if dest:
                dest = resolve_dest(dest, doc)
                pageno = pages[dest[0].objid]
                
            title_words = title.replace('\n', '').split()
            title = ' '.join(title_words)
            print('-' * level, title, ':', pageno)
            
parse(file_name,3)
```

thats work for me, getting the toc with page, you can use this file for  guide to custom logic https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/blob/master/tools/dumppdf.py